# 400 error whilst using the Fuel SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, java, fuel-sdk

I am new to marketing cloud. I am using the Fuel SDK for Java. I am trying to query data inside a data extension.

So far, I have been using my colleagues clientID and clientSecret but the problem was that I was able to get a whole list of data extension we currently have, but no fields within the data extension is currently being returned so I'm assuming it might be a read/write issues since when I output the response, all the `column` field are an empty array even though they have data in them..

This is the code:

```
ETConfiguration configuration = new ETConfiguration();
configuration.set("clientId", clientId);
configuration.set("clientSecret", clientSecret);
ETClient client = new ETClient(configuration);

//https://@@@@@@@.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx
ETSoapConnection soapConnection = new ETSoapConnection(client, "https://@@@@@@@.soap.marketingcloudapis.com");
ETFilter etf = new ETFilter();
ETExpression expression = new ETExpression();
expression.setProperty("name");
expression.setOperator("=");
expression.setValue("Customer_extension");
etf.setExpression(expression);


//Gets the table
ETResponse<ETDataExtension> response = client.retrieve(ETDataExtension.class);
System.out.println(response);
```

I have now gone and created an API Integration app in the installed packages section and it shows my clientID and clientSecret. But when I place them in the above code, I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSdkException: error obtaining access token (400 Bad Request)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.requestToken(ETClient.java:356)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.requestToken(ETClient.java:313)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.<init>(ETClient.java:159)
at com.example.soap.SoapApplication.main(SoapApplication.java:34)
```

So my question is that, how do I authenticate myself since I thought the SDK does it automatically, and secondly why are the `column` fields in the response all empty?

Comment: I believe your issue is, your new package you created uses the oAuth 2.0 method which the SDK hasn't been updated by anyone to account for the new route and method